# append dynamic data into table row jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var data = [{
  "mathid": "015-08-0011-000-01",
  "mathid1": "342-432-423-000",

  "englishid": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
  "englishid1": "342-432-423-000",

  "scienceid": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
  "scienceid1": "342-432-423-000"

}, {
  "mathid": "015-08-0011-000-02",
  "mathid1": "342-432-423-001",

  "englishid": "015-08-0011-000-01-1002",
  "englishid1": "342-432-423-001",

  "scienceid": "015-08-0011-000-01-2002",
  "scienceid1": "342-432-423-001"
}]


var tr;
var td;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  td = $('<td/>');
  if (data[i].mathid) {
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mathid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mathid1 + "</td>");
  }
  if (data[i].englishid) {
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].englishid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].englishid1 + "</td>");
  }
  if (data[i].scienceid) {
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].scienceid + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].scienceid1 + "</td>");
  }
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=  id= href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");
  $("#searchresult").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchresult">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Subject id</td>
      <td>Subject id1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

In my demo I want to add subject id and id1 to the table. I expect to add each subject to each row and each id to each td. Something is messing up the append which i cant figure out what. I don't understand what is messing my append.

Any idea is appreciated.

Expected output:

```
Subjectid | subjectid1
_______________________
mathid    | mathid1
_______________________
scienceid | scienceid1
_______________________
englishid | englishid1
```

Comment: seems to work for me

Comment: its not working it should be in one row mathid in first td and mathid1 in next td and in next row scienceid in first td and scienceid2 in next...and so on

Comment: give your expected result

Comment: @vengateshrkv like the update

Comment: @BrownmanRevival  check my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pmyfq93z/

Is this what you are after? If so the arrays were set up wrong.
You had all of the information as one item in the array, here it has been split up so that it gets put in to the correct cells.

```
var data = [{
  "mathid": "015-08-0011-000-01",
  "mathid1": "342-432-423-000"},
            {
  "englishid": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
  "englishid1": "342-432-423-000"},
            {
  "scienceid": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
  "scienceid1": "342-432-423-000"

}]
```